# Including multiple LESS files in rails asset pipeline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, less, asset-pipeline

So I broke up my LESS files in my rails app (don't ask why I'm using LESS instead of SASS) into a bunch of separate files, based off of what they are meant for.

```
stylesheets/
├── add-listing.css.less
├── application.css
├── checkout.css.less
├── dashboard-home.css.less
├── edit-listing.css.less
├── edit-profile.css.less
├── global-variables.css.less
├── global.css.less
├── inquiries.css.less
├── inquiry.css.less 
├── manifest.css.less
├── profile-listing.css.less
├── questionnaire.css.less
├── scaffolds.css.less
├── scrape.rb
├── screen.css.less
├── search.css.less
├── settings.css.less
└── sign-up-log-in.css.less
```

What I've found is that `require_tree .` doesn't work in `application.css`. I need to load `global-variables.css.less` first, and it won't do that. Even when I say `require global-variables.css.less` it still won't render the actual LESS file needed for the root page.

So what I've been doing is putting `@import` statements for all the files in `manifest.css.less`. It works, but that means that if I make a new LESS file, I have to add an `@import` statement each time. It's just another step, and I was wondering if there was anyway that I could do this with Rails. Any suggestions?

Comment: As far as i know, this is indeed the way to go, but yes, it's crappy.

Comment: which version of rails do you have ??

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem unique to LESS. In SASS, one also has the problem that one cannot ensure the order in which require_tree includes files. If for instance you want to have a `variables.scss` file that contains a bunch of global SASS variables, you have to remove the require_tree and do this instead in application.css:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require main
*/
```

Then this in main.css.scss:

```
// Import this first so other .scss files can see the variables and the bootstrap stuff
@import "variables";

// @import everything else here. If you add a new file, it won't show up until you add a line to import it here.
@import "style";
@import "tables";
//etc
```

And yes, it's cumbersome.